# How to use Radio button group id for switch, in Android, between different fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am a newbie.

Using navigation bar, fragments in the app.

**Files description:**

**fragment_settings.xml:** Contains radio button group

**SettingsFragment.java:** Basically to show the fragment_settings.xml, when Settings is clicked in the navigation drawer. I have checked different

**MainFragment.java:** Here, **I want to use the RadioButton id, which is clicked into the switch case** and then perform operations accordingly.

But the problem is control is coming in the switch but not in the cases, I tried by putting toast but the id is not matching to any case.

**fragment_settings.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.threefriends.filecrypto.SettingsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose algorithm:"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioAlgorithms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioaes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AES (Default)"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiodes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DES"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioidea"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="IDEA"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiocustom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Custom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
    package com.threefriends.filecrypto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment
{


    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    RadioGroup radiogroup;
    RadioButton aes, des, idea, custom;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
 public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    SettingsFragment settingsfragment;

    //Defined for file edittext.
    EditText editText2;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
       });
        final int id = ((RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radioAlgorithms)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        final Button b2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.encb);    //Encrypt Button
        Button b3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.decb);      //Decrypt Button

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Starting..."+R.id.radioAlgorithms, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // click related code goes here
                switch(id)    //This id is not matching to any case.
                {
                    case R.id.radioaes: {
                               //Code for aes algorithm.
                               break;
                    case R.id.radiodes: {
                               //Code for des algorithm.
                               break;
                     }
                    case R.id.radioidea: {
                               //Code for idea algorithm.
                               break;
                    }
                    case R.id.radiocustom: {
                                //My custom algorithm code.
                                break;
                    }
                }
}
        });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you

```
final RadioGroup group= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAlgorithms);
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        int id = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.radioaes:
                // Your code
                break;
            case R.id.radiodes:
                // Your code
                break;
            case R.id.radioidea:
                // Your code
                break;
            case R.id.radiocustom:
                // Your code
                break;
            default:
                // Your code
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr7, its not working, now also, I thinks there id is my own defined variable above switch while getId() is related to taking View's id.

Comment: `v.getId()` returns your current radio button id of which you clicked on

Comment: else, you can get the selected radio button id like
`int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();`

Comment: its not working now also, Sir, what I am doing is to get the checked radio button id, from the Settings(Fragment), and use that in switch, at Home (Fragment), both fragments present in navigation drawer.

Comment: are you getting control into `switch` ?

Comment: @Bati you are inflating the fragment_settings.xml from Settings class, but you wrote the radio buttons code in Main Fragment. you cann't directly communicate btw two fragments, better move the radio button listener code to your activity

Comment: Sir, but there is need to communicate between the two. If I write the code in fragment_settings.xml, then also I have to send the editText from Main Fragment. What I am trying is, the app works after taking some (i) input File path in edittext, (ii), then press Encrypt button (it will check the radio button status, that is, which algorithm is selected from settings (by default is aes)), then it will perform. The app is working fine without using switch, that is only for one algorithm, hardcoded.

Comment: Sir, I also tried by using if else, it is saying :Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.RadioButton.isChecked()' on a null object reference

Comment: Why didn't you just pass `i`  (rather than creating a new variable `id`) to the `switch`?

Answer (score 0):

you need setOnCheckedChangeListener.

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    }
});
```